# Working on figuring out how to call an array using a function to print said array?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to call an array from a function and print out the 5 numbers I had in the array.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int i;
    int n;

    void printArray(int n, int i);

    int main(void){
        int n[5]={42, 30, 45, 3, 49};

        printf("%s%13s\n", "Element", "Value");

        printArray(int n,int i);
    }

    void printArray(int n, int i){

    for(i =0; i<5; ++i){

        printf("%7u%13d\n",i,n[i]);
    }
```

Comment: The name of the array (`n`) decomposes to the address of the 0th element 
 (`&n[0]`).  In other words, pass the address of the array to `printArray`.

Comment: How do I do that exactly? Functions confuse me.

Comment: Do you have a good book on C that'll progressively teach you?

Comment: The one I have is written by someone who understands C but not how to teach it.

Comment: You can't "call an array".  You can pass the address of the first element of an array as an argument to a function when you call the function.

Comment: @HenryGibbs If you're looking for a new book, I read *C Primer Plus* by *Stephen Prata* and thought is was very well written.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I'll give it go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    // int i;  Don't use global variables
    // int n;  

    void printArray(int n[], int num_to_print);  // Tell n is array using []

    int main(void){
        int n[5]={42, 30, 45, 3, 49};

        printf("%s%13s\n", "Element", "Value");

        printArray(n, 5);   // Don't use any types when calling the function
    }

    void printArray(int n[], int num_to_print){     // Tell n is array using []

        for(int i=0; i<num_to_print; ++i){

            printf("%7d%13d\n", i, n[i]);
        }
    }
```

If you always want to **print exactly 5 elements** you can do:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void printArray(int n[]);

    int main(void){
        int n[5]={42, 30, 45, 3, 49};

        printf("%s%13s\n", "Element", "Value");

        printArray(n);
    }

    void printArray(int n[]){

        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){

            printf("%7d%13d\n", i, n[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So by adding num_to_print it then allows the func to be called in main?

Comment: @HenryGibbs Well... no... not really. The problem with your code was that you repeated the types when you called the function. You did like: `printArray(int n,int i);` which is wrong due to the `int`

Comment: how can I change the output to list element as 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @HenryGibbs Perhaps you want to do: `printf("%7d%13d\n", i, n[i]);` ==> `printf("%7d%13d\n", i+1, n[i]);` (notice the `i+1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printArray(int n[], int i);
int main(void){

int n[5]={42, 30, 45, 3, 49};

printf("%s%13s\n", "Element", "Value");
printArray(n,5);
}

 void printArray(int n[], int num){
 int i;
 for(i =0; i<num; ++i){

printf("%7d%13d\n",i,n[i]);
}
}
```

In function calling , don't use datatypes i.e.., Don't specify them . Again in function call you are using i , which is not declared before ,that's also wrong.